# Password security app for particular app

Tags: ios, objective-c, passwords

I need your views regarding the password lock concept application. Could it be possible to make the password lock security application for the installed apps in the iPhone. Suppose Whats app is installed in the device and I need the password lock concept for the What's app same as android device. So that when I click on the Whats app, first it opens my password lock application then user unlock the app then it enters to the particular whats app.

Help me if someone has an any idea regarding this concept.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe that there is any way to do this on iOS - Perhaps with a jailbroken device.

Comment: Are u sure @Paulw11...

Comment: I am sure you can't do it on a non-jailbroken device.  I haven't ever worked with jailbroken devices, so I am not sure whether it is or isn't possible on a jailbroken device.  Some MDMs can wrap apps in additional security, but the app needs to be compiled with support for the wrapper and you need to distribute the app via a private, enterprise app store